# Streamplot always in foreground

Tags: matplotlib, z-order

When drawing an `Artist` with `streamplot` the second appears always in the foreground, although the drawing is made before the `Artist`:

[image]

The same done with `pcolormesh` looks like expected:

[image]

This is the code for both pictures:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

Y, X = np.mgrid[-3:3:100j, -3:3:100j]
U = -1 - X**2 + Y
V = 1 + X - Y**2
speed = np.sqrt(U*U + V*V)

fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots()
working = False
if working:
    strm = ax0.pcolormesh(X, Y, U, cmap=plt.cm.autumn)
else:
    strm = ax0.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=U, linewidth=2, cmap=plt.cm.autumn)
    fig0.colorbar(strm.lines)

#fig1, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
#ax1.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=[0.5, 1])
#
#lw = 5*speed / speed.max()
#ax2.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=0.6, color='k', linewidth=lw)

e = Rectangle(xy=(0,0), width=1, height=1)
e.set_facecolor([0.9,0.9,0.9])
ax0.add_artist(e)

plt.show()
```

What can I do so the `Artist` overlays the `streamplot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the z-order of Artists.  For your example, try:

```
e = Rectangle(xy=(0,0), width=1, height=1, zorder=10)
```

According to [a matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html), the default z-order seems to be:

- Patch / PatchCollection    => 1
- Line2D / LineCollection    => 2
- Text                       => 3

This would explain why the streamplot (lines) would be drawn on top of the rectangle (a patch).

Comment: Ah, too simple :-) I did not think it would work since streamplot has no zorder parameter. Thank you!